# Your communities list is not visible in mobile web on site where you don’t have an account

Tags: bug, mobile-web, communities-list

If you don’t have an account for some site, you can still see a list of your communities via top bar menu of this site, e.g. on 3D Printing:

> [image: 3d]

But this works only for full web, in mobile web «sign up or log in» is shown:

> [image: 3d mobile]

When you have an account then the list of your communities is shown even for mobile web:

> [image: site when you have an account]

Comment: Probably SBD. You can't flag comments via mobile or do a handful of other things either.

Comment: @Nij what is SBD?

Comment: Status by design.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign] in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: @Nij I don't think it is by design. See updated question.

Comment: @iDebug I don't think this is by design, since the behavior should be the same on the mobile site.